# Canvas zoomIn/zoomOut: how to avoid loss of image quality?

Tags: image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code that I used for scaling images. To zoomIn and zoomOut is use the code `scalePicture(1.10, drawingContext);` and `scalePicture(0.90, drawingContext);`. I perform that operations on a off screen canvas and then copy the image back to the original screen.

I make use of the offscreen processing since the browser optimizes the image operations by using double buffering. I am still having the issue that when I zoomIn by around 400% and then zoomOut back to the original size, there is a significant loss of image quality.

**I am not depending on the original image because the user can perform many operations such as clip, crop, rotate, annotate and I need to stack all the operations on the original image**.

Can anyone throw some advice/suggestions around any means to preserve the quality of the image while not sacrificing the performance and quality.

```
    scalePicture : function(scalePercent, operatingCanvasContext) {
      var w = operatingCanvasContext.canvas.width,
           h = operatingCanvasContext.canvas.height,
           sw = w * scalePercent,
           sh = h * scalePercent,
           operatingCanvas = operatingCanvasContext.canvas;
       var canvasPic = new Image();
       operatingCanvasContext.save();
       canvasPic.src = operatingCanvas.toDataURL();
       operatingCanvasContext.clearRect (0,0, operatingCanvas.width, operatingCanvas.height);
       operatingCanvasContext.translate(operatingCanvas.width/2, operatingCanvas.height/2);
       canvasPic.onload = function () {
           operatingCanvasContext.drawImage(canvasPic, -sw/2 , -sh/2 , sw, sh);
           operatingCanvasContext.translate(-operatingCanvas.width/2, -operatingCanvas.height/2);
           operatingCanvasContext.restore();
       };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas is draw and forget. There is no way to preserve original quality without referencing the original source.

I would suggest to reconstruct the recorded stack but using a transformation matrix for the changes in scale, rotation etc. Then apply the accumulated matrix on the *original* image. This will preserve the optimal quality as well as provide some gain in performance (as you only draw the last and current state).

Similar for clipping, calculate and merge the clipping regions using the same matrix and apply clip before drawing in the original image in the final step. And similar with text etc.

It's a bit too broad to show an example that does all these steps, but here is an example showing how to use accumulated matrix transforms on the original image preserving optimal quality. You can see that you can zoom in and out, rotate and the image will in each instance render at optimal quality.

## Example of Concept

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), img = new Image;   // these lines just for demo init.
img.onload = demo;
ctx.fillText("Loading image...", 20, 20);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/sPrSId0.jpg";

function demo() {
  render(); 
  zin.onclick = zoomIn;                          // accumulates transform, but render
  zout.onclick = zoomOut;                        //  based on original image using.
  zrot.onclick = rotate;                         //  current transformation matrix
}

function render() {ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)}     // render original image

function zoomIn() {
  ctx.translate(c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.5);  // pivot = center
  ctx.scale(1.05, 1.05);
  ctx.translate(-c.width * 0.5, -c.height * 0.5);
  render();
}

function zoomOut() {
  ctx.translate(c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.5);
  ctx.scale(1/1.05, 1/1.05);
  ctx.translate(-c.width * 0.5, -c.height * 0.5);
  render();
}

function rotate() {
  ctx.translate(c.width * 0.5, c.height * 0.5);
  ctx.rotate(0.3);
  ctx.translate(-c.width * 0.5, -c.height * 0.5);
  render();
}
```

```html
<button id=zin>Zoom in</button>
<button id=zout>Zoom out</button>
<button id=zrot>Rotate</button><br>
<canvas id=c width=640 height=378></canvas>
```

Comment: Thx. Learnt about globalCompositeOperation today. Will keep experimenting.